# complex function -singular points of function

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

I'm trying to find which kind of singularity infinity is of the function

$$
f(z) = \frac{\cos(z + i) - 1}{(z + i)^4}
$$

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Verify that $f(\frac {n\pi} 2-i) \to 0$ whereas $|f(i(n-1))| \to \infty$. These facts imply that $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Comment: thanks...i couldnt understand why   |f(i(n−1))|→∞ ?

Comment: There is $e^{n}$ in the numerator and $n^{4}$ in the denominator.  It is a standard fact (proved using L'Hospital's Rule that $\frac {e^{x}} {x^{k}} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ for any $k \in \mathbb N$